# WP Database repair

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I couldn't access my wp-admin (the front end is working so far).

WP System told me to add the `WP_ALLOW_REPAIR` to true in `wp-config.php`.

I did.

I pressed the repair database and got the following messages:

```
wp_users: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
wp_usermeta: 9 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_posts: 21 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_comments: 33 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_options: Table is marked as crashed
wp_postmeta: 28 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_terms: 3 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_term_taxonomy: 18 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_term_relationships: 18 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_commentmeta: 26 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
```

Is this a solvable problem, or should I... just... find some hills to run to :/

Main, business site. Worried. What gives? Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress administration. Try asking on [wordpress.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: I didn't get response from there.. So, I decided to put here on Stackoverflow... I was not aware people look here about brands and company concern before helping some one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you posted indicates a problem with the wp_options table. Normally this is recoverable by issuing a repair command (Make a backup of the all data before doing any operations). To issue the command you can use phpMyAdmin or whatever client you prefer:

```
REPAIR TABLE wp_options
```

More info about this command: [MySQL Reference Manual: REPAIR TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html)

If this doesn't help, try issuing the command with the following arguments:

```
REPAIR TABLE wp_options EXTENDED
```

or

```
REPAIR TABLE wp_options USE_FRM
```

Read the info about USE_FRM in the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

Try access to your server phpmyadmin pannel, then select your database and then select all the tables, on the lower part of the main page showing your tables you'll see a dropdown menu open it and select the "Repair Tables" option

http://www.siteground.com/img/knox/tutorials/uploaded_images/images/phpmyadmin/31.jpg

Hope it helps you